# Define a sequence recursively in Java

Tags: java, recursion, sequence

Need help with this problem, I am very bad at recursion. I need to write a method that does this:

The input variable X is an integer between 1 and 50. The function should return as Y the X-th term of a sequence defined recursively by:

`f(1) = 1
 f(2) = 3 
 f(X) = 2*f(X-1) – 2*f(X-2)  for X = 3,4,5,...`

Your function code should use recursion (not a loop)

TBH I dont even know where to get started.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is my current code:

```
package p1parta;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RecursiveSeq
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       System.out.println("Please enter a number:");
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

       int x = input.nextInt();

       System.out.println(sequence(x));
    }

    public static int sequence(int x)
    {
        if(x == 1){
           return 1;
        }
        if (x == 2){
           return 3;
        }
        return 2 * sequence(x - 1) - 2 * sequence(x - 2);
    }
}
```

I tried to implement the solution shown but the output I get from the program do not match what I am calculating by hand. In fact just testing inputs 3,4,5,and 6 The only one that matches is 5

Comment: Start with implementing the base cases -- "if x is 1, return 1; if it's 2, return 3." Then, implement the recursive step -- "otherwise, return 2*f(X-1) – 2*f(X-2)". More than that, this question is broad, as it doesn't tell us which of the concepts involved you're having trouble with.

Comment: List what you expect and what you're getting. For example for input 3, the algorithm will return 2*3 - 2*1 = 4. You're saying that you think 4 is the wrong result for input 3? What did you expect then?

Comment: It doesn't appear that you've made any attempt to debug this on your own.  Stack Overflow will not debug programs for you unless you've shown effort to debug yourself.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: It seems that your code exactly matches the formula that you've provided. I don't see an issue here. Could you double check your manual calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a perfect use case for recursion. In general the recursive pattern is:

```
func(context)
    if simple case
        return simple answer
    else
        call func(simpler context)
        and return combined results
```

Have a go at implementing using this pattern and come back if you have issues.

Comment: I tried to implement this solution but the output I get from the program do not match what I am calculating by hand.  In fact just testing inputs 3,4,5,and 6 The only one that matches is 5.

Comment: @yshavit that's a fair point. I'll remove the code and leave the hint

Comment: @GrumpyWizard You should have a go at implementing it yourself and debugging then come back with questions if you can't get it to work.